# How to add a condition in _.flatMap loop and append it in a className using reacJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, conditional-statements

I need to add a className based on the condtion in flatmap looping.

previousDataJson

```
  var previousDataJson =      {  
      "Queue1": "req_ares_crt1",
      "Queue2": "req_cres_crt2",
      "Queue3": "req_rres_crt3",  
    }
{_.flatMap(previousDataJson, (value,key) => 

                <div className="columns">
                <div className="column">                   
                  <div className={"transaction__info " + ({if(previousDataJson[key] != newDataJson[key]){ return "bg-blue"  }})}>
                    <span className="transaction__title">
                    {key}:
                    </span>
                    <div className="transaction__desc">
                    <span style={{wordBreak:'break-all'}}>
                        {value}
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              )}
```

I need to add the classname dynamically based on the conditions.

Comment: can you add sample values for `previousDataJson `?

Comment: @Harish : I have added the previousDataJson sample data in the question

Answer (score 1):

`className={"transaction__info" + (previousDataJson[key]!==newDataJson[key]?" bg-blue":"")}`

Are you taking an error or isn't it compiling?

Or

You can use style object instead of appending classnames